# Is there anything bad about using $_SESSION in Laravel 5.8 and if so what and why?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I am trying to access a Laravel 5.8 session and unset an array inside an object in the session but I cant seem to figure it out.

I can use native php `$_SESSION` and just `unset($_SESSION["object"]->myarray[row_number])` and all is good in the world but It does not seem that easy with Laravel sessions.

I would like to avoid Laravel sessions all together and use the native php to save time and finish this project and I am just wondering if there are any long term Cons to using native php sessions in laravel

I have searched google and Laravel docs but can't find anything on accessing objects with multidimensional arrays in Laravel.

Comment: Why don't you just use `session()->put('name', $value);`? Then `session()->get('name');` to retrieve it? You said you wanted to avoid "Laravel Sessions" But that's just PHP Sessions with some Laravel magic in the middle to help you... So you don't need to post questions on Stack Overflow :P

Comment: Going of what @stokoe0990 said, you can even use `session(['key' => 'value])` and retrieve using `session('key');`

Comment: What kind of problem do you have with the session service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to avoid Laravel sessions all together and use the native php to save time and finish this project and I am just wondering if there are any long term Cons to using native php sessions in laravel

This is a little tricky as it verges way from Stack Overflow’s remit into opinions, but here goes:

You should always use Laravel’s functions where possible as it provides you with protection that you may not be aware of, and it future-proofs changes. It also keeps your code consistent.

For example, if you wanted to change how you store session variables in the future, you would have to re-write every piece of code where you’ve used `$_SESSION["object"]`. Using Laravel’s interface means that if you were to change how this was stored in the future, you would not have to update your code in your site to reflect this change.

See other suggestions on better ways to write this using Laravel, but to answer the question “Is there anything bad about using $_SESSION in Laravel 5.8 and if so what and why?” – yes, in short.

Comment: Does anyone know of any other Con's to using native php sessions in laravel 5.8?

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar problem to the OP, but rather than a matter of convenience I have co-residing micro apps that behave as if they are a single monolith on the same domain.  For this I need everything to use the same shared session database so I can keep people signed in across applications.  It works great for all of the non laravel apps, but now I want to start moving things to Laravel; so I need some mechanism to adapt Laravel to work with PHP "native" sessions.

Answer (score 1):

In `Laravel` you can utilize the session vars like so. Link to [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session).

```
$request->session()->get('object');
```

You should be able to do what you want with something similar like.

```
$index = 0;
$request->session()->forget('object.myarray.' . index);
```

Comment: Use `$request->session()->forget('key');` when removing session data.

Comment: yes thanks, did not think you could nest that call so you can and is a viable solution.

Comment: Not working for me, no error given, no unset happening either.

Comment: i guess you replaced the index with your own row number?

Comment: can you post your session var with dd($request->session()->get('object'));

Comment: Yes I did. I don't need to delete the first item in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this  `$value = $request->session()->get('key.value')`;

See [session docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session)

Comment: Please add some more explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

for a multidimensional array for

```
$tempCategories = array(
    0 => array(
        'cat' => 'Wood'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'cat' => 'Metal'
    ),
);
<h5>{{$cat['cat']}}</h5>
```